# How to get stack trace of blocked statements in JMC Console?

Tags: java, profiling, jmc

I'm using Java Mission Control to profile my application. Amongst the useful metrics in the "Threads" tab is the number of times each thread was blocked. However, I can't seem to find a way to get which lines of code threads were blocked on. Is there a way - either programatically or via JMC - to work out where the blocking is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the different stack traces in the Hot Methods subtab on the Threads/Hot Threads tab, click a thread to see the stack traces only for that.

In JMC 6 you see the same info in the Lock Instances page, and the stack traces in the Stack Trace view.

Comment: I can't seem to find the Lock Instances. I'm using JMC 6

Comment: It should be in the Outline view, as a child under the Java Application page

Comment: I must be really stupid, I just see "An outline is not available" under the outline view.

Comment: "An outline is not available" is what you would see if you have no fligh recording (JFR file) opened.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need to use Flight Recorder? I was assuming that it can be done with JMX console only

Comment: Even using flight recorder, I don't see how your answer is an answer to my question. The Lock Instances shows me nothing, at least when doing a 1 minute recording of the JVM running JMC. Hence, no upvote or accepted answer.